# Why is it recommended that built-in DB should not be used in Production environment for Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, h2

In the Sonar documentation, its said that the built-in DB (H2) should only be used for testing purposes and not on production environments. What are the limitations of using this db for Sonar ?

Comment: Perfect question. Needs to be reopened